# Season 2 Episodes 1-10 is/are now available. Which is correct?

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

Which is correct? Season 2 Episodes 1-10 is/are now available.

Comment: Are, there are ten episodes

Comment: But with parentheses it could be: *Season 2 (Episodes 1-10) is available.*  This is one season available.

Comment: Available as **a unit,** so use ***is***. Buy *it,* not *them.*

Comment: Or simply, Season 2,  Episode 1 to 10,  now available.

Comment: It depends on whether you (a) wish to use 'formal' (ie in line with the form of the noun) or 'logical' (ie in line with your buying say 1 box or 10 DVDs) concord, and (b) {having chosen 'logical concord'} wish to indicate the fact there is one set / purchase / season's offerings or 10 discs / episodes. People saying there is one correct answer here are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Available as **a unit**, so use *is*. Buy *it*, not them.